# magnificpopup/lightbox only fires once

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I have read some similar things on stackOverflow, but I am really not getting anywhere. We use magnificpopup with lightbox to display excursion details and photos.It works fine on the first click, but fails to fire again unless the page is refreshed. Obviously, this won't work! Here are the code/calls. Can anyone assist?

the code that is clicked: 
blah, blah Excursion Name

Here is the JS settings:

```
var lb_settings = {
    type: 'inline',
    fixedBgPos: true,
    closeBtnInside: true,
    preloader: false,
    removalDelay: 300,
    mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in',
    callbacks: {
        close: function() {
            // need to stop cycle when its no longer in the DOM
            var $lb = $(".cc_lightbox_slideshow");
            if ($lb.length) {   
                $lb.cycle('destroy');
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And lastly the actual click function:

```
$("code").click(function () {
    var href = "/trips/getOptionDetails/acct_id/" +$(this).attr("class") + "/year/" + programYear + "/program/" + program;
    lb_settings.items = {};
    lb_settings.items.src = href;
    lb_settings.items.type = 'ajax';
    $.magnificPopup.open(lb_settings);
});
```

I'd be very grateful for your help. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: I would be VERY grateful for and assistance someone can provide. I have a Monday deadline and this is the only thing left to wrap up the project!

Comment: wow. I'm an idiot. The settings under my JS settings are for another use. It is only the code click section that is being used. I think I need to figure out how to remove the instance from the DOM. As you can probably tell, I'm new to the whole jQuery thing so I'm struggling. Plus, I just took this site over.

Answer (score 0):

This way WAY easier that I though. I'm finding that the previous developer has a real knack for over complicating things.

I changed the ajax call to simply:

$('.magPopUp').magnificPopup({
  type: 'ajax'
});

Then I just used a simple html href as such:

a href="linkWithUrlParameters" class="magPopUp">link text

Lastly, I switched the lightbox settings and calls to run directly from the file being called. Voila!

Thanks everyone.